# Spring: Idiom for achieving imperative wiring in a declarative Spring XML config?

Tags: java, spring

I am a user of `class A`, which is provided to me as a library.

In my Spring config, I specify an `A bean`, which Spring happily instantiates for me.

As a side effect, `A` creates its own instance of `B`, which it exposes via `A.getB()`.

`B` exposes a `set()` method that I wish to invoke with a `C` that I configure in Spring.

How do I do this?

I've looked at util:property-path to reference the `B` but that won't let me put any content inside of it.

I also looked at proxying but there just seems to be no way to get a hold of `B` and do something to it while I am trapped within the declarative world.

Repeat, I cannot create `B`.

It is created only as a side effect of the creation of `A`.

There are no convenience methods on `A` allowing me to call `A.setC()`.

Comment: Thanks for the responses guys, I'll have to try these out before I accept an answer and things just got hairy on a different part of the project so it will be later.  Stay tuned...

Answer (score 1):

Spring does provide mechanisms to allow one Spring bean to act as the factory for another, but it's an approach that rapidly runs into difficult when you start chaining factories together - the declarative approach doesn't work too well there.

When you have non-trivial arrangements like you've described, it's generally easier to implement your own [FactoryBean](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/beans/factory/FactoryBean.html), which becomes responsible for instantiating your non-bean-friendly object graph. The `FactoryBean` is injected with all of the necessary collaborators, and then [does the wiring up manually](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/beans.html#beans-factory-extension-factorybean), giving you your desired imperative approach.

This pattern is generally used to configure legacy components that don't have IoC-friendly signatures, but it's just as useful for building whole graphs of interacting objects.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [factory methods](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/beans.html#beans-factory-class-instance-factory-method). They allow you to tell Spring to obtain B via another path than using a constructor (via A in your example).

Comment: That says "instantiation using an instance factory method is where a non-static method of an existing bean from the container is invoked to create a new bean."  That would work if the library provided an A.createB() method.  But it does not.  B is already created, as a side effect, and all I have available to me is A.getB().

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [FactoryBean](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/beans.html#beans-factory-extension-factorybean)

The scheme with FactoryBean is as follows:

- define your bean with

  ```
  <bean id="myBean" class="myFactoryClass">
        <property name="c" ref="yourObjectToBeInjectedInC" />
  </bean>
  ```
- create your factory class which implements `FactoryBean`.
- define a property named `c` (with a setter/getter)
- define a property of type `A`, called `instance` for examle.
- in the `afterPropertiesSet` method, instantiate call `this.a = new A();`, and then `a.getB().setC(this.c);`
- in the `getObject()` method (required by the `BeanFactory` interface) add `return instance`;
- make `isSingleton()` return `true` (if you don't want it to be prototype, of course)
- make `getObjectClass()` return `A.class`;

You can now freely inject `myBean` (of type `A`).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that B gets instantiated when A is constructed, have you considered this?

```
<bean id="a" class="com.example.A">
    <property name="b.c" ref="c"/>
</bean>

<bean id="c" class="com.example.C" />
```

Comment: I did a quick test before posting the answer, so yes.